# find_element_by_xpath does not work when I automating downloading a csv

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate download a file from a database using selenium in python. I find the xpath by right click on the button and then copy the xpath. In my python code, I used find_element_by_xpath after open the website using chromedriver. But it returned an empty list but not an element. This problem was driving me crazy. Have anyone run into this problem?

Here is the code:

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.option import Options
def test_sanity():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome() _= 
    browser.get("ebi.ac.uk/chembl/g/#browse/activities/filter/…) 
    download = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(""".//*[@id="GladosMainContent"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/a[1]""") 
    print(download) 
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def test_sanity():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    _= browser.get("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/g/#browse/activities/filter/target_chembl_id%3ACHEMBL5455")
    download = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(""".//*[@id="GladosMainContent"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/a[1]""")

    print(download)
    time.sleep(3)

Comment: find_elements_by_xpath returns an empty list and when I used find_element_by_xpath, I run into this no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpa...}. any new ideas?

Comment: BTW, I found the XPath by right click in Chrome then, Inspect > Copy > Copy XPath.

Comment: Oh, sorry for taking your time. I thought I included the whole url: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/g/#browse/activities/filter/target_chembl_id%3ACHEMBL5455   . The "csv" download button is on the top right of the website. (not exactly the top).

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  It seems you are an expert about Selenium. So it is hard for you, then I would move on and keep this problem in the back of my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait until the page is loaded completely, in order to interact with the `CSV` button. This completely synchronization issue. Below is the script with the sychronization.

**imports needed:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**script:**

```
url = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/g/#browse/activities/filter/target_chembl_id%3ACHEMBL5455"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# navigate to application
driver.get(url)
# wait for the CSV Link and then click
csvLink = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-format='CSV']")))
csvLink.click()
# wait for the download link and click
hereLink = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".BCK-download-messages-container .BCK-download-link-container a")))
hereLink.click()
# wait for 10 seconds for the downloading to finish
time.sleep(10) # check if there is another option available to make sure if the download is completed, otherwise use this hard coded wait.
```

Comment: The "here" link was still there. But the website will be closed by the python program if I don't let it wait for the downloading to complete after clicking the "here" button.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I have accepted the answer.